# C# Interacting with CLI Process - Standard Input Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, command-line-interface, cisco

I've written the following code. For some reason the StreamWriter / RedirectStandardInput does not seem to be working. The CLI that i'm trying to interact with does not seem to accept or even receive the commands that I input.

There are a few other odd things that I also don't understand. I have to use a While loop to read all the lines of StandardOuput.

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Returns nothing. Only *ReadLine();* seems to be recognized.

**EDIT**

I have also noticed now that if I set breakpoints after any process.StandardInput.WriteLine(""); call, the breakpoint is never reached. The process never returns back to my C# code.

This also occurs after my process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() loops. When it reaches the last line it never returns to my c# code.

The code is below:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();


        process.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("connect vpn.service.domain.com");

        line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("0");

        line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("MyUsername");

        line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("MyPassword");

        line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        }
```

The Output that I receive in my debug console is:

```
CLI Says: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 3.1.10010) .
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: Copyright (c) 2004 - 2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says:   >> state: Disconnected
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: VPN> 
CLI Says:   >> state: Disconnected
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: VPN> 
CLI Says:   >> notice: Ready to connect.
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: VPN> 
CLI Says:   >> registered with local VPN subsystem.
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: 
CLI Says: VPN>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadToEnd()` won't return until the end of the stream has been encountered. To say it another way, after `ReadToEnd()` has returned, the stream is in a state such that no more data will ever come out of it (you've reached the end).

As such, you probably don't mean to use `ReadToEnd()`. Depending on how you process the output, you might want to use `ReadLine()`, or just `Read()`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but ReadLine() and Read() still don't return when the last line is reached.

It seems that an EOF isnt recognized properly?

Comment: ReadLine() will only be null when the stream has ended, therefore I think your loops are stuck trying to read the entire stream still. You probably just want ReadLine without the loop? (it will block until it encounters a new line)

Comment: @Michael - If the process you're opening never stops on its own (and never closes its own standard out), then no Read method will ever reach the end of the stream. I think you're confusing the difference between the stream not having any more data at the moment, versus the stream actually being closed. When the stream is closed, you will continue to read any leftover buffered data, until finally ReadLine returns null, or Read returns indicating zero bytes were read.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops will continue until the stream ends:

```
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
    }
```

This will read the entire stream printing it out line by line, only stopping once the stream actually ends. The ReadLine() function will read in each character of the stream until it gets to a carriage return and then returns all the characters it read as a string. It will only return null upon the stream ending.

What you need to do is process each line and figure out what you want to do with it, aka put the logic inside the read loop something like:

```
    enum State {
        Initial,
        Connecting,
        ..
    }

    string line = string.Empty;
    State state = State.Initial;
    while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CLI Says: " + line);
        if(line == string.Empty) continue; // skip blank lines
        if(line.StartsWith("VPN>")
        {
            switch(state) 
            { 
               case State.Initial: 
                   SendConnect(); 
                   state = State.Connecting;
                   break;
               ..
            }
        }
        else // check what is being printed by vpn is correct, no errors, etc.
    }
```

You can then expand upon the switch statement, progressing the state as you go and sending different inputs, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue. I've inserted break points before and after process.StandardInput.WriteLine() as well as before an after the StandardOutput loops. When I step into process.StandardInput.WriteLine() the code immediately stops executing and focus is returned to my main form (winform). The breakpoint (or any other code) following process.StandardInput.WriteLine() is never executed. The same thing happens when the very last process.StandardOutput.WriteLine() is called in the loop.